# How can I associate these models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I've built a system of products and a shopping cart in my rails app and I'm using Devise for user authentication. These have 3 models. Products, Carts and Users models.

The goal I have is to associate saved products from a cart with a columns from a user model. If the users has three products with ids 1,2,3 in a cart and clicks on a "Save" button in the cart, the ids (integers) of those products should be saved in User string columns.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HABTM = has_and_belongs_to_many 
HABTMT = has_many trough: ( has_and_belongs_to_many_through )

You'd need a HABTM association between User and Cart.
Although I'm not going to use HABTM because I don't personally like it. I believe HABTMT is more appropriate, always.

```
class User
  has_one :cart
  has_many :products, though: :cart
end

class Product
  has_one :cart
end

class Cart
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product

  validates_uniqueness_of :user, scope: :product # ensure a User can only have one product
end
```

Also, the advantage you'd have from HABTMT is that you can add an extra column in your Model that holds such information like Quantity of products, discount codes etc..

**EDIT**

Example on one of the possibility of interacting with Product / User association.

It really depends on how you plan to design your User Interaction between the Product and the User itself.
For example, if you decide to add a `Add to Cart` button that sends and AJAX request to the CartController,
/cart/new/product/32 you'd probably have the `new` function like this:

```
def new
  @cart = Cart.new
end

def create
  @cart = Cart.new(cart_params).merge({ user_id: current_user.id, product_id: params[:product_id] })
end

def cart_params
  params.require(:cart).permit(
    :user_id,
    :product_id
  )
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you know how to actually save product data to a user column? I guess I need to add something to a cart controller?

Comment: @MarkoI. See my edit. It really depends on how you design your interaction, really. Most of the work will have to be done on the Form, rather than the controller. Rails will do most of the hard work for you, that's the beauty of it.

Comment: @MarkoI. if you have a github repo with your project maybe I can be more helpful.

Comment: I'll pull the project down and spin it up. I think I'm going to open a pull request for you, it's easier than carrying on on here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114110/discussion-between-marko-i-and-vlad).